# HP LaserJet M1536DNF network scanning on Scientific Linux 6.4 - Error during device I/O

Tags: scanner

```
[root@NOTEBOOK ~]# scanimage -L
device `hpaio:/usb/HP_LaserJet_M1536dnf_MFP?serial=ZZXXYYXXYYXX' is a
Hewlett-Packard HP_LaserJet_M1536dnf_MFP all-in-one

[root@NOTEBOOK ~]# scanimage --format=tiff > a.tiff
scanimage: open of device
hpaio:/usb/HP_LaserJet_M1536dnf_MFP?serial=ZZXXYYXXYYXX failed: Error during device I/O

[root@NOTEBOOK ~]# dmesg
usb 1-3: new high speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=012a
usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 1-3: Product: HP LaserJet M1536dnf MFP
usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
usb 1-3: SerialNumber: ZZXXYYXXYYXX
usb 1-3: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 5 if 1 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x03F0 pid
0x012A
type=1400 audit(1380474171.846:23488): avc:  denied  { module_request } for
 pid=5354 comm="udev-configure-" kmod="net-pf-10"
scontext=system_u:system_r:cupsd_config_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
tcontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tclass=system
type=1400 audit(1380474171.849:23489): avc:  denied  { module_request } for
 pid=5354 comm="udev-configure-" kmod="net-pf-10"
scontext=system_u:system_r:cupsd_config_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
tcontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tclass=system
type=1400 audit(1380474171.849:23490): avc:  denied  { module_request } for
pid=5354 comm="udev-configure-" kmod="net-pf-10"
scontext=system_u:system_r:cupsd_config_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
tcontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tclass=system

[root@NOTEBOOK ~]# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0483:2016 SGS Thomson Microelectronics Fingerprint
Reader
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 17ef:1003 Lenovo Integrated Smart Card Reader
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 03f0:012a Hewlett-Packard

[root@NOTEBOOK ~]# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:
:base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: Scientific
Description: Scientific Linux release 6.4 (Carbon)
Release: 6.4
Codename: Carbon

[root@NOTEBOOK ~]# rpm -qa|egrep -i 'hp|scan|sane'
hpijs-3.12.4-4.el6_4.1.x86_64
hplip-common-3.12.4-4.el6_4.1.x86_64
xsane-0.997-8.el6.x86_64
xsane-common-0.997-8.el6.x86_64
sane-backends-libs-1.0.21-3.el6.x86_64
hplip-libs-3.12.4-4.el6_4.1.x86_64
sane-backends-libs-gphoto2-1.0.21-3.el6.x86_64
libsane-hpaio-3.12.4-4.el6_4.1.x86_64
sane-backends-1.0.21-3.el6.x86_64
[root@NOTEBOOK ~]#
```

**Q:** can someone bring the HP LaserJet M1536DNF scanner via network to life? - since scanning over USB isn't working..

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: besides a scanner cannot scan? The scanner cannot scan.

Answer (score -1):

Install hplip-gui in Synaptic package manager. (it is not installed by default). HPLIP Toolbox will appear in the start menu, open it, you will see the HP logo in the bottom panel right corner. Then open xsane, and a window will pop-up prompt you to install a "plug-in", that is it, follow the instruction and the scan driver will be installed automatically.

If the plug-in does not install itself, right-click on the HP icon in the bottom panel, and open HP device manager, click on menu list:"Device" - "Diagonose HPLIP driver", follow instruction and you might fix your problem.